# Why timeout data(heartbeat) is empty?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

[image]

For testing heartbeat, I think  "the above 6th column" is actual heartbeat value. Is it right?
If true, what's the meaning of empty for rabbitmq-c client. Rabbitmq-c client always stay there and never die.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Heartbeat interval can be suggested by the server, but the client might not take that value. I was looking the the [source](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/librabbitmq/amqp.h) and you might be able to use this function:

```c
AMQP_PUBLIC_FUNCTION
int
AMQP_CALL amqp_tune_connection(amqp_connection_state_t state,
                               int channel_max,
                               int frame_max,
                               int heartbeat);
```